# Flex order property not working as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get "Mac and cheese is really yum!" underneath "The main content of the site".

```css
#content {
  padding: 0;
  background: 0;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
}
.heading {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
#content h1 {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  font: 2.538em/1.3em;
  color: #393939;
}
#content .text {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>Mac and Cheese</h1>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Mac and cheese is really yum!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    The main content of the site</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KMPydJ

Any help is appreciated -- thanks!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - [Jens Meiert's index of properties](http://meiert.com/en/indices/css-properties/) is a great reference for those kind of searches.

Answer (score 9):

The CSS `order` property applies only to siblings.

In your code, you are trying to re-position `.text`, which is a child of a flex item (`.heading`), to appear after `.main-content`.

Well, `.heading` and `.main-content` are siblings. But `.text` is like a niece to `.main-content`, so the `order` property won't work.

Once `.text` an `.main-content` are siblings you can achieve the ordering you want.

In the revised code below, I've removed your `.heading` element. Now the `h1`, `.text` and `.main-content` are all siblings.

```css
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  font: 2.538em/1.3em;
  color: #393939;
}
.text {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>Mac and Cheese</h1>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Mac and cheese is really yum!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">The main content of the site</div>
</div>
```

Learn more about the `order` property here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/3597276