# Add a row to a nested flex container on media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries, flexbox

I have one primary container that holds all the `div`s using a `flex-direction` of row.

A second container that is nested holds two `div`s that have a `flex-direction` of column, to stack up two `div`s in one row in the outer container.

Using `flex-box` and media query, I was attempting to change the existing two row column `div` 'smaller-container' into a three row column div once the browser width is less than 1000px.

I tried doing this by creating a third empty `div` within `smaller-container` *and swapping its order with a div outside the smaller-container* once the browser width is less than 1000px.

It didn't work. I think this is because the two `div`s in question (the empty div and the outer div) are at a different nesting level.

It would be great if someone can find a solution to turn the two row in one column to three row in one column.

Even better if that solution has no need of a nested container. Javascript solution is also welcome if it doesn't require a plugin.

Image of how it should look:

[image]

```css
/*Basic Reset*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  max-width: 1366px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.box-1 {
  order: 1;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
}
.smaller-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  order: 2;
}
.box-2 {
  order: 3;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
}
.box-3 {
  order: 4;
  background-color: green;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
}
.box-4 {
  order: 5;
  width: 100%;
}
.box-5 {
  order: 6;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .box-2 {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .box-3 {
    height: 50px;
  }
  /******* Here we swap the empty div that hasbeen existing in the smaller container
        with an outer div ********/
  .box-5 {
    order: 5;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .box-4 {
    order: 6;
    background-color: purple;
    height: 150px;
  }
}
[image of desired solution][1] [1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlvlx.png
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="smaller-container">
    <div class="box-2"></div>
    <div class="box-3"></div>
    <div class="box-4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-5"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lukindo/nuv603h9/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're right that the `order` property doesn't work at different nesting levels. [It only works among siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37449839/3597276).

Scripting is one option you can pursue. Another, a bit hackish, is to duplicate an HTML element. Specifically, place the orange box element (`.box-5`) in both the primary and nested container.

Then use `display: none` on both orange and purple boxes per your media query.

Here's an example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  max-width: 1366px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.box-1 {
  order: 1;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
}
.smaller-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 50%;
  order: 2;
}
.box-2 {
  order: 3;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
}
.box-3 {
  order: 4;
  background-color: green;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
}
.smaller-container > .box5 {
  display: none;
}
.container > .box-5 {
  order: 6;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .box-2 {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .box-3 {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .container > .box-4 {
    order: 6;
    background-color: purple;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .smaller-container > .box-5 {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100%;
    order: 6;
  }
  .container > .box-5 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="smaller-container">
    <div class="box-2"></div>
    <div class="box-3"></div>
    <div class="box-5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-4"></div>
  <div class="box-5"></div>
</div>
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9as3zco1/9/)