# Using the flex order property across multiple containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="container-1">
    <div class="child-1-1"></div>
    <div class="child-1-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="container-2">
    <div class="child-2-1"></div>
    <div class="child-2-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can apply a display of **flex** to *wrapper*, and then make *container-2* appear above *container-1* using **order**.

I would like the final order of the elements to be:

1. child-2-1
2. child-1-1
3. child-1-2
4. child-2-2

What I basically want is for the children of the two containers to pretend as if their parents are not there, and instead take their ordering from the outer *wrapper*.

This could of course be achieved via either duplicating the components and hiding/showing depending on the breakpoint, or via JS - so no points for suggesting those.

Comment: What are you trying to do? can you just have a wrapper that wraps child-2-2 and child-1-1 ?

Comment: A diagram of your desired layout would be helpful, by setting `order: -1` on` #container-2` (and a `flex-flow: column` on `.wrapper`, child-2-2 does appear above child-1-1. Where should child-2-1 appear in your desired circumstance?

Comment: I'm talking theoretically, but as a real-world example imagine container-1 and container-2 are left and right columns in desktop mode, but in mobile mode they appear stacked. However, as that pushes the contents of container-2 far down the page, I want to bring child-2-1 at the top. but retain the order of the rest of the elements.

Comment: Consider getting rid of your inner containers and instead using `flex-basis` (the third parameter of `flex`) and `order` to position the children where you want at various breakpoints. You definitely **cannot**, using just flexbox and the markup you have provided, achieve your desired result. Can't do it, full stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flex `order` property applies only to siblings in the same container.

So using `order` to re-arrange a series of flex items spread across different containers will not work.

But based on your requirements, it doesn't appear you need multiple containers. All items can exist in a single container.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child-1-1 { order: 1; }
.child-1-2 { order: 3; }
.child-2-1 { order: 2; }
.child-2-2 { order: 4; }

.wrapper > div {
  flex: 1 0 40%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


@media ( max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  div.child-2-1 {
    order: -1;
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child-1-1">child-1-1</div>
  <div class="child-1-2">child-1-2</div>
  <div class="child-2-1">child-2-1</div>
  <div class="child-2-2">child-2-2</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lh34juen/1/)

Learn more about the flex `order` property here:

- [Is there a “previous sibling” CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/3597276)
- [Flex order property not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37449725/3597276)